# Masonry-Rails gutters break layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, jquery-masonry

I set up masonry rails on my website and when I click the logo to go to root path, the gutters disappear as if they were never there.
Also when adding more the 4 posts for a second row it also glitches.

[Image of the posts overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzW5F.jpg)

[Image no longer overlapping after hitting the link to go to root path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ4An.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to this here
[Masonry Jquery in Rails - doesn't work without refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998903/masonry-jquery-in-rails-doesnt-work-without-refreshing-the-page)
Apparently you need to run turbolinks